# jquery Masonry height - fill gaps at container's bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I've started using jQuery [Masorny](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) plugin, I use images with fixed width of 190px each and it works fine, beside one issue. Naturally there are gaps at the bottom of each column, I want to fill theses gaps with some background. 
If I set background to the container, it will be also behinde the gutterWidth that between each element. Is there a way to add some empty divs at the bottom of each columns, or something else that will let style that gaps in the bottom?

My Masonry init code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var $gal = jQuery('#gallery');

        $gal.imagesLoaded( function(){
         $gal.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            columnWidth: 190,               
            isFitWidth:true,
            gutterWidth:2
          });
        });
    });
```

Here is a working demo for this and also there a screenshot of what I try to achieve:

http://maorb.dyndns-ip.com/masonrytest

I've looked in other questions about Masonry and also in the documentry, it seems not to be mentioned.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why it's naturally to have gaps at the bottom? Each brick in masonry can be stick together like a wall and a wall doesn't have gaps?

Comment: Yes the bricks sticks together, but it seems that sum of images' heights won't always be exactly as the height of the container, so ther rest becomes these gaps in the bottom of each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to fill the gaps at the bottom of each column because masonry sorts the bricks in vertical order and then in horizontal order. It's similar to a bin-packing algorithm with some additional math similar to a treemap algorithm. The idea of a bin-packing alogrithm is to minimize the amount of columns needed for a fixed amount of bricks to be stacked in the columns. This is a np complete problem and naturally you have gaps at the bottom (or top) and those gaps can't be filled.

For a treemap you can use a kd-tree. A good description is here: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html.

```
{
   Node* child[2]
   Rectangle rc
   int imageID
}

Node* Node::Insert(const Image& img)
if we're not a leaf then
    (try inserting into first child)
    newNode = child[0]->Insert( img )
    if newNode != NULL return newNode

    (no room, insert into second)
    return child[1]->Insert( img )
else
    (if there's already a lightmap here, return)
    if imageID != NULL return NULL

    (if we're too small, return)
    if img doesn't fit in pnode->rect
        return NULL

    (if we're just right, accept)
    if img fits perfectly in pnode->rect
        return pnode

    (otherwise, gotta split this node and create some kids)
    pnode->child[0] = new Node
    pnode->child[1] = new Node

    (decide which way to split)
    dw = rc.width - img.width
    dh = rc.height - img.height

    if dw > dh then
        child[0]->rect = Rectangle(rc.left, rc.top, 
                                   rc.left+width-1, rc.bottom)
        child[1]->rect = Rectangle(rc.left+width, rc.top, 
                                   rc.right, rc.bottom)
    else
        child[0]->rect = Rectangle(rc.left, rc.top, 
                                   rc.right, rc.top+height-1)
        child[1]->rect = Rectangle(rc.left, rc.top+height, 
                                   rc.right, rc.bottom)

    (insert into first child we created)
    return Insert( img, pnode->child[0] )
```

The question with your htmlx and html5 padding problem is simple to explain. You have a padding:8px; in the body tag in the html5 document. so there is a gap between the image and the surrounding image of 4px on each side. See my picture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chiyou, I know that and I agree that the gaps at the bottom are already minimized. I wonder, though, if there is a way let's say to add an empty div at the bottom of each column below the image, and make that empty div's height be from the last image in that column till the container's bottom border. then that div can be added a background as well. I'm trying to look maybe a js way to calculate these heights, but can't figure out this yet.

Comment: It's maximized not minimized. You want to maximize your profit not minimize. It's not possible or you must write your own algorithm.

Comment: I meant that the gaps are minimized through the grid and hence the bottom (or top) gaps at the edges. Are you familiar with another  jQuery/JS plugin that may support such "closure" of the edges?

Comment: I think Isotope isn't free but makes the same.

Comment: Isotope is free for private and cost $25 for commercial. Bu I checked and seems that it is based on Masonry, so I doubt if Isotope will make it. I think on a way to write some JS to run after Masonry to determine heights between the loswelement in container and the container's borders, and try to insert there some divs, but I can't figure out how yet.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to rewrite an algorith for that, no budget from the client for that. I'm still trying to think for a simple css/js manipulation for that.

Comment: Well, after digging more into this I found that the issue is html5 and probably how it renders elements. I found that a simple img inside a div, regardeless this gallery script, causes the div's height be 4px longer in html5 and not in xhtml. So, when I put the img in the container directly and gave the the `.item` class without wrapping them in `div`s or `li`s, giving them also `border-top` and `border-bottom` of `1px` (in the sides the is the `gutterWidth:2`), it works accurate. (continue in next comment..)

Comment: I also added a `repeat-y` of a wide 10px height background image containing the texture and the white separator of 2px at each 190px  (all widths will always be 190). So this is good. 
Look at this new demo - 
http://maorb.dyndns-ip.com/masonry/
This is with `doctype html5` and each image is wrapeed in divs. You see the gaps between each brick. But look at the bottom of the page, outside the gallery, there is a single image inside a div, with colored borders. You can see the div is longer than the image, althougt they have `margin:0;padding:0;` (continue in next comment...)

Comment: Now look at this same page but with `doctype xhtml` :
http://maorb.dyndns-ip.com/masonry/?doctype=xhtml
You can see the gallery working perfect, and see the bottom image and div does not have gap.

So, Now this becomes a different question now, why this is happening in html5? I'd like to use html5 in that site, and I must wrap my images items in a div/li since they will contain some data above each image.

Comment: @Maor: I don't know why this happens maybe ask another question?  I think it's much simplier to find a solution in Javascript. Btw. I'm a freelancer and I've experience with Masonry and bin-packing you can hire me if you want? I also need some money? Look at my homepage http://www.chihoang.de. I've also the masonry plugin. The problem is that's a bin-packing alogrithm not really make to please your eyes.

Comment: @Maor: I've added some information about your padding problem and html5 and xhtml problem. I hope it helps.

Comment: At last, as I felt before, there is a simple css solution found for this in html5 - the `.item` brick element should be added css of `line-height:0;` and that solves that gap at the div's bottom and Masonry works perfectly now in html5 too. That's great, as you may see in the [demo](http://maorb.dyndns-ip.com/masonry/).
@Chiyou Thank you for all your help, suggestions and ideas. I will accept here your answer for all you efforts. I may need some freelnace jobs later on and will be glad to be in contact.

Comment: btw: I've just now seen the edit you made on your first reply with the css padding 8px. There isn't and wasn't padding:8px there for no elemnet, this is very weird..